# Consecutive phased X rotation gates simplification

Tags: programming, gate-synthesis

I have two consecutive phased X rotation (see cirq [PhasedXPowGate](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/cirq/PhasedXPowGate) gate definition), how to find both t' and p' angles (according to previoux cirq definition) so that two consecutive PhasedXPowGate are simplified in one PhasedXPowGate gate with these t' and p' angles ?

In other words, I'm searching t' and p' so that PhasedXPowGate(t', p') = PhasedXPowGate(t1, p1)*PhasedXPowGate(t2, p2)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, in Cirq, the `PhasedXPowGate(p,t)` is defined as:
$$Z^pX^tZ^{-p},$$
where $t$,$p\in\mathbb{R}$, and $X$,$Z$ are the Pauli X and Z operators.

The product of two of these gates would be:

$$Z^{p_1}X^{t_1}Z^{-{p_1}}Z^{p_2}X^{t_2}Z^{-{p_2}},$$

My first guess seeing the structure of the gate was to think about commutation relations of the Pauli matrices, i.e. $X$ and $Z$ anti-commute. However, this relation doesn't hold for any choice of $p$ and $t$. There is no guarantee that you can find a closed form expression that satisfies the following equation
$$X^{a}Z^{b}=\alpha Z^{a'}X^{b'},$$
which in turn makes it impossible to find a set of $t'$,$p'$ that satisfy your equation:
$$Z^{p'}X^{t'}Z^{-{p'}} = Z^{p_1}X^{t_1}Z^{-{p_1}}Z^{p_2}X^{t_2}Z^{-{p_2}}$$

This can also be understood intuitively if you use the Bloch sphere representation. You can visualize this `PhasedXPowGate(p,t)` as an rotation on the XY-plane, with $p$ determines the axis in the XY-plane about which a rotation of amount determined by $t$ occurs.

If you think of it as XY-rotations, and assuming $p_1$ and $p_2$ do not hold some relation, the two rotations are made along different axes on the XY-plane and therefore the total operation may not be described by a rotation on the XY-plan anymore, making your equation impossible to solve.